# Filtering LogsEntry

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I'm trying to run this Queryset in Django to the model LogEntry.

```
logs_entry = LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type_id = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Regime).pk, object_id__in = user_regimes.values_list('id', flat = True))
```

But throws this error: `You might need to add explicit type casts.`

What kind of cast can I use? to make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have the problem in this line
>
> ```
> user_regimes.values_list('id', flat = True)
> # <QuerySet [15, 9, 16, 10, 17, 11, 12, 13, 14]>
> ```
>
> *values_list()* returns QuerySet not list

To make it work use `list()` function

```
user_ids = list(user_regimes.values_list('id', flat = True))
# [15, 9, 16, 10, 17, 11, 12, 13, 14]

logs_entry = LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type_id = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Regime).pk, object_id__in = user_ids)
```